# Attempting to print table headers to each page of a pdf on Excel export

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a workbook where I am formatting data and then printing to a PDF for delivery to clients. What I would like to do is take my table headers, which are in range A4:F4 on the fist page, I want that to appear as A1:F1 on subsequent pages.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
'************* Formats Data as Table ******************************

MyTableRange = Range("a4:" & myrange).Address

        Range("A4:F4").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(MyTableRange), , xlYes).Name = "NewTable"
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("NewTable").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium1"
        
        
'************* Set Table Headers to Repeat ******************************
  
     Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "A4:F4"
        End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
  
  

'*********** Formatting the File Name for the Export *************

    dt = Format(Now, "mm.dd.yyyy hh mm")
    fName = EXPORTS & "AccountEnding" & AccountNumber & " - Created On - "
    
    If Len(Dir(fName & ".pdf")) > 0 Then sep = " - "
    fName = fName & sep & dt & ".pdf"
    
'***********Setting Export to PDF Parameters***********

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With Sheets("LTXN Report").PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
       
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: [Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printtitlerows) uses `address`. Try that?

Comment: So I tried using that and it gave me an object error. I went and corrected the code to ```Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$4:$4"
        .PrintTitleColumns = "A:F"
    
        End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True``` 

Now out of nowhere it is forcing it to fit all rows to one page on print. Any idea why it would do that??

Comment: I think you wanted to try `Rows(4).Address`

Comment: @findwindow so I did that and it works, but now it is forcing all rows to fit on one page. I even have it manually inserting a horizontal page break every 35 rows and it overrides it. Any idea why that would be?